# What is E_POINTER and E_INVALIDARG?

Tags: com, com-interop

I'm trying to write a browser helper object.. and sometimes I need to return E_INVALIDARG but I dont know what the value for this constant is. Is there a list of these constants in .net interop services somewhere?  I've been searching the namespace in the object browser and I cant find it..

or do I not understand what I'm doing?  Can someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See here: [Common HRESULT values](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa378137.aspx).

```
E_POINTER    = 0x80004003
E_INVALIDARG = 0x80070057
```